# Getting 404 page not found error while hit api url from postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

this is my controller

```
  public function show($id)
    {
         echo $data=Poll_model::find($id);
        // echo $data=DB::select('Select * form tbl_poll where id=?',[$id]);
        //echo "string";

    }
```

and i hit this url from postman
http://localhost/total/public/api/1

it show 404 error page not found

but

when i hit http://localhost/total/public/api

it's 100% working and show my data.

this is my route list.
[image]

Comment: Please show your route for `show` function

Comment: now check it. @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: Can you show your route declaration please from routes file?

Comment: @MihirBhende  this is how i done. 
Route::resource('/','Poll');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have your route declaration as :

`Route::resource('/','Poll');`

Laravel is going to create all routes with primary url structure as `http://localhost/total/public/api/`

If you want to have a module called poll and then it's resource routes :

```
`Route::resource('polls','\App\Http\Controllers\Poll');`
```

This will give you urls like :

```
GET `http://localhost/total/public/api/polls`
GET `http://localhost/total/public/api/polls/create`
POST`http://localhost/total/public/api/polls`
GET `http://localhost/total/public/api/polls/{poll}`
GET `http://localhost/total/public/api/polls/{poll}/edit`
PUT/PATCH `http://localhost/total/public/api/polls/{poll}`
DELETE`http://localhost/total/public/api/polls/{poll}`
```

I would like to recommend naming controller as `PollController` instead of just `Poll` as it is easy to know that it is a controller class.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) for more help.

Answer (score -1):

please update your route for show method and try like:

```
Route::get('poll/{id}/show', 'App\Http\Controllers\Poll@show');
```

then your url like:

http://localhost/total/public/api/poll/1/show